# Pandas, asignar codigo postal segun ciudad

Tags: python, pandas

Queria saber si hay alguna forma de hacer esto en la que no tenga que hacer una iteracion por el df

```
#codigos postales
cps = pd.DataFrame({'cp':  ['100', '200', '300'],
                    'city': ['a', 'b', 'c']
                    })
#df de ciudades
city = pd.DataFrame({'city':['a', 'b', 'c','a', 'a'],
                    'codp':[0,0,0,0,0]})

for i in range(len(city)):
  city['codp'][i] = cps[cps['city'] == city['city'][i]]['cp']
```

Lo que intento hacer es asignar el codigo postal *(codp)* correspondiente a cada ciudad en base al df con la lista de codigos postales. La idea es que el df ***city*** termine viendose asi:

| city | codp |
| --- | --- |
| 'a' | 100 |
| 'b' | 200 |
| 'c' | 300 |
| 'a' | 100 |
| 'a' | 100 |

Comment: Buen día, ¿Si hay forma de hacer qué? No sabemos lo que deseas hacer con el código que muestras, por favor edita la pregunta y agrega un ejemplo del `dataframe` resultante que deseas obtener.

Comment: Gracias por el feedback y la disposicion! Espero que se entienda mejor lo que estoy preguntando.

Comment: Buen día @JSN, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo puedes hacer muy fácilmente con [`pandas.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) utilizando `cps` y configurando que el índice sea "city".

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

cps = pd.DataFrame({'cp':  ['100', '200', '300'],
                    'city': ['a', 'b', 'c']
                    })
city = pd.DataFrame({'city':['a', 'b', 'c','a', 'a'],
                    'codp':[0,0,0,0,0]})

city['codp'] = city.join(cps.set_index('city'), on='city')['cp']
print(city)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
  city codp
0    a  100
1    b  200
2    c  300
3    a  100
4    a  100
```